Nonblocking child process output read
I can't figure why I can't proper communicate with child process.
I have program in C and python. Python need to start C program and then capture output from C in nonblocking way. In the example the C program will output 10 lines per second and will terminate after 5 seconds.

The ccode.c compiled with: gcc -D arch_X86 ccode.c -o ccode.bin

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

uint64_t nanos(void){
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    return ts.tv_sec*1000000000ull + ts.tv_nsec;
}


int main(){
    printf("\nC Code Started\n");
    uint64_t nowns, ns;
    int16_t n=0;
    nowns=nanos();
    ns=nanos();
    while ((nanos()-nowns)<5000000000UL){
        if ((nanos()-ns) > 100000000UL){
            ns=nanos();
            printf("From C I got %i\n", n);
            n++;
        }
    }
    printf("C code exit\n");
}

and python script:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import subprocess
import time

pr=subprocess.Popen( ['./ccode.bin'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)

while True:
    print (pr.stdout.read(1), end='' )

When I start python the program is blocked for 5 seconds and then 50 lines are printed in once. The expected is to print 10 lines per second untin 5 second elapses. In real application Python is tkinter GUI with timer executed 10 times per second to capture output from c code.

You need to flush the stdout buffer after writing each line, or disable buffering with setvbuf().
